# How to overlap one side of two panels with dock properties of Top and Fill for each?

Tags: c#, panel, borderless

I have a borderless form for which i want to make a border by using two panels. One is to be a title holder for which I've set the dock property to top. The other one, that is to be the form content area, is set to dock property of fill.

Now, right beneath the titlebar panel, the two panel's borders 'add up' making it slightly bolder which is the problem I want to solve. Have a look at the image below.

[image: Shot]

I need the thick border just as any other side of the panel, no extra width.

Comment: Have you tried to use a [SplitContainer](http://www.dotnetperls.com/splitcontainer)?

Comment: Try setting the Margin (and possibly padding) properties to zero.

Comment: Panels are like cookies, they are easy to eat but you'll quickly gain unattractive weight.  Restoring the functionality you lost from not having a title bar anymore is *much* easier if you don't use a panel at all.  Use the form's Paint event instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want can't be done with the standard `Panel` (I'm assuming `WinForms`). You can either:

1. Create your own Panel descendant and draw it yourself (shouldn't be that hard)
2. Be Clever:

   2.1 Create a panel which covers both panels: add a border to it and set `Padding` and `Margin` to 0

   2.2 Make your top panel and bottom panel borderless and inside that parent panel

   2.3 Make a 1px height (or your border's thickness) panel docked to top, under your top panel and over your bottom (client-docked) panel, borderless but filled with the border color in the parent panel

If your borders are not 3D, this will look as you expect it to:

[image: Sample]